# Firebase authentication not working as expected

Tags: authentication, firebase

I'm following along with the firebase docs about anonymous authentication, but I must be missing something.

Here is my attempt at authenticating:

```
var dataRef = new Firebase('https://myfirebaseurl.firebaseio.com');
// Log me in
dataRef.authAnonymously(function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('Login Failed!', error);
  } else {
    console.log('Authenticated successfully with payload:', authData);
  }
});
```

The result is that I get a 'TypeError: undefined is not a function' message because 'authAnonymously()' is supposedly not defined.

I have '**Enable Anonymous User Authentication**' checked for my firebase though... and I don't know what else would keep this from being an option. Is it not offered in the 'Hacker' version?

I am running this locally, so it shouldn't be a domain permissions issue since 'localhost' is included in the default accepted domains.

Comment: What version of the JS client are you using? These new login methods came in after the 1.1 release.

Answer (score 0):

David was right.

I followed a tutorial on Firebase to setup my angular app, and I assumed that the version that tutorial was using was up to date with the version used in the docs. It was not. Just change your version to the most recent one if you were also silly enough to run into this :P.

Comment: Was it a link to a v0 version?

Comment: [Here is the tutorial](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html)  I was following. It is the first thing that pops up when you google 'angularfire'.

Comment: That makes sense. AngularFire is still on Simple Login. It's being upgraded to the 1.1+ login methods right now.

Comment: It also lists the Firebase version used in the quickstart as 1.0.21, for which all the docs would be correct.